# How to concurrently crawl paginated webpages with unknown end?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, web-crawler, rust-tokio, rust-futures

I'm trying to write a web crawler in Rust using the tokio asynchronous runtime. I want to fetch/process multiple pages asynchronously but I also want the crawler to stop when it reaches the end (in other words if there is nothing left to crawl). So far I have used [futures::future::try_join_all](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/future/fn.try_join_all.html) for getting a collective result from the async functions that I have provide as `Future`s but this obviously requires the program to know the total pages to crawl beforehand. For example:

```rs
async fn fetch(_url: String) -> Result<String, ()> {
    tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(100)).await;

    Ok(String::from("foo"))
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let search_url = "https://example.com/?page={page_num}";

    let futures = (1..=3)
        .map(|page_num| search_url.replace("{page_num}", &page_num.to_string()))
        .map(|url| fetch(url));

    let _ = futures::future::try_join_all(futures).await.unwrap();
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9bafaa40dd139960748ed91eb25921d3)

In this simple example I have to know the total pages to go through (`1..=3`) before actually fetching them. What I want is, not providing any range and have a condition to stop the whole process. (e.g. if the HTML result contains "not found")

I looked into [futures::executor::block_on](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/executor/fn.block_on.html) but I'm not sure if it is something that I can utilize for this task.

Comment: lets say, Page 1 exist, then check for page 2... every time you need to wait for previous  page to finished in order to check next page, So for this task  asynchronous will not help much, so  check then parallel... like task 1 check from 1..10, in same time task 2 will  check from 11..20,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's roughly how to do this using [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) and [`.buffered()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffered):

```
use futures::{future, stream, StreamExt};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Error;

async fn fetch_page(page: i32) -> Result<String, Error> {
    println!("fetching page: {}", page);

    // simulate loading pages
    tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
    if page < 5 {
        // successfully got page
        Ok(String::from("foo"))
    } else {
        // page doesn't exist
        Err(Error)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let pages: Vec<String> = stream::iter(1..)
        .map(fetch_page)
        .buffered(10)
        .take_while(|page| future::ready(page.is_ok()))
        .map(|page| page.unwrap())
        .collect()
        .await;

    println!("pages: {:?}", pages);
}
```

I'll go over the steps in `main()` in detail:

- [`stream::iter(1..)`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/fn.iter.html) creates an unbounded `Stream` of integers representing each page number
- [`.map(fetch_page)`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.map) of course will call `fetch_page` for each page number
- [`.buffered(10)`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffered) this will allow up to 10 `fetch_page` calls to occur concurrently and will preserve the original order
- [`.take_while(|page| future::ready(page.is_ok()))`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.take_while) will keep the stream going until a `fetch_page` returns an error, it uses [`futures::future::ready`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/future/fn.ready.html) since the function passed to `take_while` must return a future
- [`.map(|page| page.unwrap())`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.map) will pull out the successful pages, it won't panic because we know the stream will stop when any errors occur
- [`.collect()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.collect) does essentially the same thing as for an iterator except you have to `.await` it

Running the above code prints out the following, showing that it tries 10 at a time but will only return up to the first failure:

```
fetching page: 1
fetching page: 2
fetching page: 3
fetching page: 4
fetching page: 5
fetching page: 6
fetching page: 7
fetching page: 8
fetching page: 9
fetching page: 10
pages: ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"]
```

This glosses over some nice-to-haves like handling non-missing-page errors or retrying, but I hope this gives you a good foundation. In those cases you might reach for the methods on [`TryStreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html), which specially handle streams of `Result`s.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!